# Logging invalid login attempts .HTACCESS all pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, authentication

I am trying to setup a script that could log passwords of every failed HTTP Basic Auth. So if a user goes to **www.mysite.com/basicauthprotected.jpg** and if he tried something *invalid* like user:admin && pass:admin and it fails, it will be logged.

I tried to setup the chosen answer from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/460765/log-invalid-login-attempts-htpasswd) post. Anyway, for me, this script does not log *every* request, because if I go to **www.mysite.com/basicauthprotected.jpg** then it gives me an HTTP Basic Auth prompt but it does not store wrong passwords. It only stores them when I go to www.mysite.com/logging.php.

This is my ***logging.php*** script:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])):
    $fp = fopen('/log.txt', 'a+');
    $password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
    $username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $time = date('y-m-d/H:i:s');
    $request = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
    fwrite($fp, $time."\t".$request."\t".$username."/".$password."\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
endif;

ob_start();
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required",1);
header("Status: 401 Authorization Required",1);
echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you are authorized to 
 access the document
 requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
 credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
 browser doesn\'t understand how to supply
 the credentials required.</p>';
exit();

?>
```

My .***htaccess*** file looks like this:

```
# script that will store invalid login attempts
ErrorDocument 401 /logging.php

AuthName "Protected"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

# Set REMOTE_USER env variable on 401 ErrorDocument
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^401$
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{ENV:REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER}]
```

Is it possible to log every failed auth including a fake authentication to **www.mysite.com/basicauthprotected.jpg** and if so; what am I doing wrong?

Thank you guys so much! <3

Comment: I had the same issue when trying to do the same thing, it's a shared server and I can't just look at apache logs. So this approach was the best way for me to do some debugging, unfortunately I also found that this method no longer works (if it ever has).